# Border & Background Positions CSS

Tags: css, wordpress-theming

I'm currently trying to code my own Wordpress theme, and I want to make the primary menu with this style: [the border will be kind of "separate" from the background color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F1nWx.png). I'm not sure how to explain it, but I want to do something like the photo attached. :)

This is pretty much what my code looks like now:

```
.menu ul {
   background-color: white;
   box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 1px black;
   list-style: none;
   padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
   text-align: center;
   text-transform: uppercase;
   letter-spacing: 2px;
   font-family: Garamond
}
```